# How to change the path of a folder to point to one in Windows

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

Basically I'm wanting my Ubuntu music folder to direct me to my Windows music folder, so that when I click my Ubuntu music folder I see the contents of my Windows music folder. I've already got my Window partition to mount automatically so that won't be an issue. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to access your music files in your Windows mount by using your `~/Music` folder you can use `mount --bind` to mount the path to your Windows files in to your `~/Music` folder.

You could make that automatic by adding the following `/etc/fstab` line (after the line that mounts your Windows partitions) using your favorite text editor, ie:

> sudo nano /etc/fstab

```
/path_to_windows_files/music_folder /home/your_username/Music bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

where:

- path_to_windows_files/music_folder: is the path which contains the
  mounted Windows music files
- your_username: is your username or the name of the user that will
  have the files mounted

Close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and select <kbd>y</kbd> to save the file.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example? I'm assuming the command would look something like

mount --bind /path/windows/music /path/ubuntu/music

Comment: Was working on it, it should be clear now.

Comment: @forgeSHIELD if you edit your questions and add the actual paths you have things mounted to he can make it exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok I've got it in there, but have run into another problem. The path to my windows music folder has a space in it, so it looks like this:

/media/NTFS/My Name/Music

When I restart then, it tries to find the folder Name/Music which does not exist

Comment: Fixed it. To add a space in the file path you need the escape \040, so my sample path would look like: /media/NTFS/My\040Name/Music. Thank you for your help @BrunoPereira